# Typescript throwing error: "Spread types may only be created from object types.(2698)"

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror, typescript-never

The code below throws an error when attempting to spread an object after a null check. The error shows subtask as type "never" and then says I can't use spread because it's not an object even though I'm clearly checking that subtask exists before spreading it into a new object.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can resolve this error without resorting to removing type safety around the object?

```
type SubTaskFlow = 'Subtask1' | 'Subtask2'
type Status = 'NotComplete' | 'Complete'
type SubTask = {
  flow: SubTaskFlow
  status: Status
}

type Task = {
  flow: 'Task1' | 'Task2'
  subtasks: Array<SubTask> 
   status: Status
}

type Tasks = Array<Task>

const obj1:Task = {
flow: 'Task1' , 
subtasks: [{flow: 'Subtask1', status: 'NotComplete'}, {flow: 'Subtask1', status: 'NotComplete'}],
status: 'NotComplete'
}
const obj2:Task = {
flow: 'Task2', 
subtasks: [{flow: 'Subtask1', status: 'NotComplete'}, {flow: 'Subtask2', status: 'NotComplete'}],
status: 'NotComplete'
}

const testFunc = (subtaskFlow: SubTaskFlow, status: Status) => {
const tasks = [obj1, obj2]

    let subtask: SubTask | null = null
    let subtaskToUpdateIndex: number = -1
    let taskWithSubtaskToUpdateIndex: number = -1

    tasks.forEach((task, taskIndex) => {
 
        if (task.subtasks && task.subtasks.length) {
          // iterate over the subtasks to check for match
          task.subtasks.forEach((_subtask, subtaskIndex) => {
            if (_subtask.flow === subtaskFlow) {
              subtask = _subtask
              subtaskToUpdateIndex = subtaskIndex
              taskWithSubtaskToUpdateIndex = taskIndex
            }
          })
        }
      })

    

      if(subtask){
        const testsubtask = {...subtask}
      }
}
```

This TS playground better demonstrates the error:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwCoEMDOBrAYgGwPYDuUAvFAOTwLDoYCMZUAPuZdZgExkCwAUKJLGrA4aEuQByeYAGE8AWzA4IwCA2ZlZCpSu59w0SqkxiA3ryhQAZvgIAuWIiPYb5qGiEj7MD2l4BfXl5+aCdTV2tCezIneiZyJ05XNEQ2DDR7AEEAJyyUEAAeQxoAPihXNx8vH39Anlqg-SgnUVJs3IKnYtqAYzwAO3coPAQAK1pbUNIzHgi7eJpYgBoynmSqGnSoAG0TWajWBbJl9xRhTbJJGXlFZVU-Zd2bfZTD48qJKU0bnT8AXUXeCczlFLl9tKoajxegNgENRuwJjQwjMnvMOEcVmtUpsdnsWC9MPQ3qdPB8rlpbmR7lBHpF8et0cTgWSwZS-gDVu8Lp9ruDdAE6lD+oMVO4sHA+t0xAAKLE0XB0oqYBUEJmk7wktAAShIpWm0JFGzEW2GY2WpvYv1qFgs2jcBIwXkcSOYfTgOBwYjdHvKUDtcswSDwAFUwAATU4QACSfTDEAAHvY3XIEBAsmIALS0X121IAdQAlsAABYHQMh8ORmNxxNQZOp9OkLPWm3YgB0ljwWQAoihusXpdLUstUtWEzriHrzL6bVAC5YoEOaG2A2koAAyddQVIrh1oNtKPoAcxLOums4vUAA9Fe5ypciohgA3NPb4vQVeiYB4KD9iDdDArC7KA5FOfsZwvHdPw7Lte37QcAH1V2OB0x3jCcpx4S9L3nRckIdDsbBIYhSFXFUzwg7D7QZQDSHwmjKOw1cg1DCMVDQsRVzQxjL3zItSwdFjK3Y2MEzEUdRPjHibQFKiLD8LVGNki8FJbCw1JtedZQdLVz2wg1YVFYBV1MNszNXZTZwFPwgA

Comment: Seems like a bug? [This](https://tsplay.dev/WYvqrw) works using assertion

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to spread it ? Couldn't you just assign it to `testsubtask` ? :D

Comment: I can actually use Object.assign and it works as expected, but I'm trying to understand why spread doesn't work in this case. It seems like TS is unable to infer subtask as potentially being an object since I'm setting it to null, even though I assert it can be an object and do a null check at the bottom of the example